# Inconsistent return from std::isblank between Visual C++ and gcc. Which one is wrong?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, locale

I'm seeing inconsistent behavior in a call to `std::isblank` between Visual C++ on Windows and gcc on Ubuntu and I'm wondering which one is correct.

On both compilers -- when the default locale is the "C" locale -- the following call returns false

```
std::isblank('\n');
```

This is what I expect.  And it squares with what I see on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isblank)

> In the default C locale, only space (0x20) and horizontal tab (0x09)
>   are classified as blank characters.

However with C++, we also have the version that takes a `std::locale` argument

```
std::isblank('\n', std::locale::classic());
```

Here I am supplying `std::locale::classic`.  Shouldn't that be the equivalent to the previous call?  Because when I call this second version on Windows, it returns true.  It considers a newline to be a blank character.  Linux still says false.

Is my understanding (about `std::locale::classic`) correct?  And if so, is the Visual C++ version wrong?

Comment: Depends how classic you want to get.  It makes it consistent with what the OS assumes.  Underlying call is [GetStringTypeA()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318117(v=vs.85).aspx), retrieving the C1_TYPE for a character. \n is AT&T, \r\n is DEC and \n was pretty blank on the teletype :)  Pretty typical Windows approach, it strongly avoids having multiple oracles.

Comment: I want classic to be what the standard says it should be and what their own CRT version of the function and documentation says.  Anyway I submitted it and they admitted it's a known problem so I guess that's that.

Comment: I know, I know, nobody ever cares why it is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, MSVS is wrong.  **[locale.statics]** states:

> ```
> static const locale& classic();
> ```
>
> 4. The "C" locale.
> 5. Returns: A locale that implements the classic "C" locale semantics, equivalent to the value locale("C").
> 6. Remarks: This locale, its facets, and their member functions, do not change with time.

Thus the following:

```
std::isblank('\n', std::locale::classic());
```

Is the same as:

```
std::isblank('\n');
```

Where `locale("C")` has been called.